# rich:tooltip not correctly displayed in IE(9)

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, tooltip

I have a tooltip set for an h:selectOneRadio which is correctly displayed in FF and Chrome but not in IE(9).
In the latter case what appears is a tooltip which goes beyond the left margin and just to the right margin of the page.

Here is how it appears in FF/Chrome:
[image]

and here in IE
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.subscriptionFormFieldSubscriptionType}:" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <h:selectOneRadio id="subscriptionType"
                      value="#{detailModel.afterObject.subscriptionType}"
      <f:selectItems value="#{detailModel.subscriptionTypeValues}" />

      <rich:tooltip id="tt1" styleClass="tooltip" for="detailForm:subscriptionType" layout="block" >
        <span style="white-space: nowrap">
          <h:outputText value="#{msg.subscriptionToolTipForSubscriptionType}" escape="false"/>
        </span>
      </rich:tooltip>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <h:messages for="subscriptionType" style="color:red; font-size:12px;" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I took the richfaces showcase sample (which works correctly in IE too) as sample, so I don't know where the problem is. Any idea/hint?

If more information is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found: `layout="block"` was causing the problem.